# Populating a pdf template with html, css and php variable

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, pdf-generation

Here's what i'm trying to do. I have a Student Result Application in which i'll like to print out a pdf format of a specially designed Result's Sheet.. Example Here......

http://www.4shared.com/photo/yg8vCjYe/results_layout.html

My question is that is it possible to send all the html, css and php variables from the final result sheet to the pdf engine, or just design a new page result_printout.php page and implement the pdf engine on that page.

I'll be happy your honest opinions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe take a look at wkhtmltopdf, although I'm not sure if this would suit your needs:

- http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/
- http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltoimage_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html